# Is it really enough for the overload protection of a wire to follow these equations Ιb ≤ In ≤ Iz and I 2 ≤ 1.45 x Iz (2)?

Tags: wire, short-circuit

As stated in many technical documents (eg [this](https://library.e.abb.com/public/114371fcc8e0456096db42d614bead67/2CDC400002D0201_view.pdf)), for overload protection of a wire the following must be true:

[image]

At the same time, for short-circuit protection of the wire, we must calculate the expected short circuit current at the beginning and at the end of the wire, calculate the let-through energy and check if: I^2*t<(k*S)^2.

1. What is the relation between I2 and In? Is it I2=1.45*In? Where on the B-curve is I2?
2. Assume we have an overload of 1.3*In (using a B-curve MCB) and we have chosen a wire such that In=Iz. Is it possible that the MCB doesnt trip? **Doesnt that mean that the wire may eventually burn?** Is it really enough for the overload protection of a wire to follow these equations Ιb ≤ In  ≤ Iz  and I 2 ≤ 1.45 x Iz  (2)?
3. In [this](https://library.e.abb.com/public/a009c7093209baf248257d170031c80a/CTLG%20ProM%20FINAL%20LOW%20(A).pdf) ΑΒΒ catalog (pg 281) we are advised to calculate the short circuit for both sides of the wire (close and far from the source). **Why do we seem to care more about calculating short circuit and not so much about overload protection?**

[image: Tripping characteristics B, C, D Tripping characteristics K, Z in accordance with IEC/EN 60898-1] [image: Load limit curve for PVC-insulated cables]

4. Could we just compare the B-curve of our MCB to the "Load limit curve for PVC-insulated cables" (taking in consideration how the environment of these cables/wires affect this graph) and make sure that the **wire graph is always above B-curve?** **Or is it very complicated and the method stated above is just enough?**

Comment: The MCB has a thermal and magnetic component. The thermal is for long term overload and the magnetic for gross overload. You can see in the graph that the curve type is mainly for gross overload

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer only to the question number 1.

According to a [document](https://www.ti-soft.com/en/support/help/electricaldesign/project/distribution/circuits/circuit-protection-checks/protection-against-overload) from TiSoft:

For MCBs
The overload condition (1) (Ιb ≤ In ≤ Iz) must of course be met. But if (1) is true, the overload condition (2) (I2 ≤ 1.45 x Iz) is also true for an MCB complying with IEC standards, as depicted bellow:

[image]

However, for Low-voltage fuses complying with IEC 60269-2-1, I2 = 1.6 x In. Therefore, condition (2) becomes: In ≤ 0.9 x Iz.

---

Regarding question number 2, [the abb](https://library.e.abb.com/public/114371fcc8e0456096db42d614bead67/2CDC400002D0201_view.pdf) document (which was mentioned in the question) states that:

> In individual cases, conditions (1) and
> (2) may not guarantee complete
> protection in accordance with the rules
> as aforesaid may not assure protection
> in certain cases, **for example where
> sustained overcurrents less than I2
> occur.** In such cases, consideration
> should be given to selecting a cable
> with a larger cross-section area.

So it seems that an overload of 1.3*In may actually put the wire in danger.